# Filter Node Information on the Server in OPC UA

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I try to understand the OPC UA Services a search a Method to return some nodes specified by their Sensor value.

For example, we have a node which has five children. The Sensor value of the first and second children are below 100 and the rest is above.
Now I want to return all child nodes with a value below 100.

I thought about using browse() to get all children and then use read() to get their attributes and check the values, but that seams to be very inefficient for me.

Furthermore, it would be nice if the OPC UA Server return just the nodes below 100.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Query](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Part4/5.9.1/) service is supposed to provide you that, but the problem is that the servers do not typically support it, yet. So you will probably have to read the values yourself. Note that you can read several values with one read call.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help.
I suppose I have to use from the Content Filter the GreaterThanOrEqual operator where operand[0] is the value of one of the child nodes and operand[1] a literal value containing the number 100?
So if I can't use Query, I have to use the browse call to get all nodeIds of the children, then use the read call to get all values and check them on the Client side, right?
Is there a way to get the corresponding nodeId to the values of the read call?

Comment: I just read more about the Content Filter and am a little confused. Is it even possible to send a comparing value like the value 100 from the client to the server or do I have to create a new Node with that value, then compare the other nodes with it and then delete it?

Comment: Content Filter works with the Query service. But, since you probably cannot use Query, you cannot use the filter either. So, you will have to browse and Read as you had already been doing. Browse provides you the NodeIds, of course.

Comment: Is there a way to check if a Server supports the Query service?
I tried to find some sources for the fact that not all OPC UA Servers support Query but but the only thing I can find is in Specification 4 is the quote "**Servers that support Query are...**" but that doesn't proof much.

Comment: You can always try to call it, and see if the server responds with Bad_NotSupported.